# Import docx.js library

Tags: javascript

How would I use a NPM library such as docx in salesforce?

The folder hierarchy seems large to upload as a static resource. Please advise

Answer (score 2):

You can't reliably use node modules directly from the node_modules directory. Instead, you would want to [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify) your code. I won't go in to too much detail, but the general synopsis is that you'd install browserify, install any modules you need, then write a main script that `require`s any necessary modules, exports functions, etc. At this point, you should be able to import the single JS file as a static resource.

Comment: Hey @sfdcfox - is this still the case in 2023?